# Issue in handling the states of two events into single state

Tags: reactjs

I have predefined areas to be selected from the dropdown. If option other (specified Area) is selected then a text box will appear. Below is the code

`

```
      <Dropdown.Toggle  variant="primary" id="dropdown-basic">
      {selectedLocality || '--Select Your Locality--'}
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu>
      <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleLocalityChange('Pathanwadi')}>Pathanwadi</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleLocalityChange('Sanjay Nagar')}>Sanjay Nagar</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleLocalityChange('Kurar Village')}>Kurar Village</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleLocalityChange('Highway')}>Highway</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleLocalityChange('Upper Govind Nagar')}>Upper Govind Nagar</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleLocalityChange('Other (Specified Area)')}>Other (Specified Area)</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
   
    </Dropdown>
  </Form.Group>
  {selectedLocality === 'Other (Specified Area)' && (

    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
      <Form.Label className="required">Specify Your Area:</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        required
        placeholder="Enter your specified area"
        value={specifiedArea}
        onChange={handleSpecifiedAreaChange}
      />
    </Form.Group>
     )}`
```

I tried to capture the value of textbox if 'Other Specified Area' is selected through onchange event. but it is not showing blank value.

`  const handleLocalityChange = (selectedLocality) => {
setSelectedLocality(selectedLocality);

```
    if (selectedLocality === 'Other (Specified Area)') {
      setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, locality: specifiedArea }));
    } else {
      setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, locality: selectedLocality }));
    }
  };`
```

I am handling onchange state as shown above but it is not working. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your onChange callback doesn't update your "specifiedArea" state as you put it in `Form.Control.value`. if specifiedArea is part of formData, then it must be updated in onChange callback and not use from old prevFormData. it maybe should be like :

```
setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, specifiedArea: e.target.value}));
```

and also i think you don't need the if statement `if (selectedLocality === 'Other (Specified Area)')` because your text field is display when selectedLocality equal to 'Other...'